# Discover MongoDB Database Hostname on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I need to connect to a MongoDB (Heroku) database through Pentaho, but I can't find the HostName anywhere. Does anyone know where I can find out?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Heroku, but probably you'll have a configuration panel somewhere with the data to connect to the database, I would ask on Heroku about it.
This link is not directly related, but explains how to add to Heroku a Config Var with the URI of the MongoDB connection to an Atlas MongoDB database, probably you'll have something similar: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/use-atlas-on-heroku/